# How to get the available space on Android sdcard?

Tags: android, environment, sd-card

I am using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to create a file and I will need to know if there is enough space available before I create and store the file.

If you can cite the Android Ref doc, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [StatFs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) Class.  Here is an example of how to use it taken from the source code to the Settings application found on the phone.

```
        if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        try {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
            long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
            long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();

            mSdSize.setSummary(formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize));
            mSdAvail.setSummary(formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize) + readOnly);

            mSdMountToggle.setEnabled(true);
            mSdMountToggle.setTitle(mRes.getString(R.string.sd_eject));
            mSdMountToggle.setSummary(mRes.getString(R.string.sd_eject_summary));

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // this can occur if the SD card is removed, but we haven't received the 
            // ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED Intent yet.
            status = Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED;
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate the code.  I am seeing differences with the external management from Eclair to Froyo.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`StatFS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html). It should work if you pass in the value from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to the constructor (converting to `String`, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I see the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to restat to get accurate results:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
stat.restat(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
long available = ((long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Usable since API level 9:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getUsableSpace();
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace%28%29)